# Calling a public method of a destroyed fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

Is it possible to call the public methods of a destroyed fragment? I'm talking about fragments in viewPager. When I press back button the fragment gets destroyed so if I call a method of this fragment, will it be executed?

Comment: No, that method will not be executed. you have to create a method in container activity/fragment of viewpager.

Comment: Meaning? I have viewpager, so how can I create a container along with it?

Comment: your viewpager must be a part of some activity/fragment you have to create that method in that activity/fragment.

Comment: OK, so you are saying that the host activity should contain the public method of its fragment, only then I can call, right?

Comment: Yes. then you can call that method.

Comment: But the problem is, this method has variables that belong to the fragment XML. So if I define them in host activity, how can I find them by ID, will it not give me npe?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164103/discussion-between-aj-27-and-rektirino).

Comment: check if the fragments is null before calling the method

Comment: and if it is null?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can call public methods on a destroyed fragment, as long as the instance in your activity is still existing.
I tested it and verified that the fragment is destroyed, by calling the following fragment method from the activity after removing the fragment:

```
public void test() {
        Log.d("Fragment", "Current State " + this.getLifecycle().getCurrentState().toString());
    }
```

This method ran and returned `DESTROYED`